# p-table reset is not working in angular 8 for PrimeNG table

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

Hi I am using angular 8 and PrimeNG version 6. I want to reset the p-table on button click. I am getting error see below.

```js
    import { Table } from 'primeng/table';

        @ViewChild('dt', { static: false }) Component
        table: Table;
        onClick() {

            this.table.reset();
        }
```

Error Getting after click :

```
KpientryComponent.html:146 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined
    at KpientryComponent.onClick (kpientry.component.ts:145)
```

Comment: `table` is undefined variable and you don't initialize it with another value.

Answer (score 0):

The Table component in not declared correctly.  The `@ViewChild('dt')` is the `Table` variable.  Preform the reset on `dt`

```js
import { Table } from "primeng/table";

@Component({
  selector: "app-table",
  templateUrl: "./app-table.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app-table.component.css"]
})
export class AppTableComponent {
  @ViewChild("dt", { static: false }) public dt: Table;

  onClick() {
    this.dt.reset();
  }
}
```